# SQLite Database locking up on Delete Command

Tags: java, sqlite, locking

I have a problem where I can't seem to get this simple delete command working. Everytime I run it it just locks the database and crashes

The id parameter exists in the database
the database is small. Only a few tables.
update commands work completely fine.

The id is an in and resulting command is - `DELETE from Employees where ID = 2;`

```
public static void EmployeeDeleteByID(int idIn){

     Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
          c = Connect();
          c.setAutoCommit(false);
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

          stmt = c.createStatement();
          String sql = "DELETE from Employees where ID = " + idIn + ";";
          System.out.println(sql);
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
          c.commit();
          stmt.close();
          c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println("Error 1 : " +  e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully");


}
```

Error after running : `java.sql.SQLException: database is locked`

Comment: So you say it does not even print "Opened database successfully"?

Comment: yes it opens the database correctly then attempts delete command. this is from the console Opened database successfully
DELETE from Employees where ID LIKE "2";
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked. Also the same connect() method works on Update methods that work fine.

Comment: Didnt seem to work but ill try again. Ah just realised something. The ID type in Database is Integer and not int does this make a difference? ID is also a unique index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"database is locked" means that some other connection still has an active transaction.

If there is no other process accessing the database, you have to check all connections in your program; at least one of them forgot a `commit()`.

Comment: Ive literally started from opening the program and narrowed it down to this method. Where should the commit be or how do i manage it? Only other query that seems to run before this is creating a JTable with SQL Query but its not locking the database. Its locking with the delete command.

Comment: *Some* database access is locking the database. When you say there is only one, you have found the culprit.

Comment: I dont think it is because for example if i have the program open i can run the update command fine proving the database isnt locked by displaying the JTable. Its is 100% this code in the original post causing the issue somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The code actually works fine.

It turned out another method was being called to fill a JCombo which was keeping a connection open due to an error being caused by calling a null value from database.

It wasnt obvious as there was no code in the exception box.

Silly little problem so people always make an error throw some kind of stack trace or warning.

Thanks